# Checking vector equality by comparing each element doesn't match with `==` operator

Tags: c++, stdvector

I tried to check if two `std::vector`s are equivalent, by implementing custom functions.

But the results don't match with that of the `==` operator.

(Even though my functions say the two vectors are the same, `vector1 == vector2` *sometimes* says the two vectors are not the same.)

Below is the code I wrote. (removed some `std::cout`s)

Implementation 1:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool isVecSame(std::vector<T1> v1, std::vector<T2> v2) { 
    bool bSame = true; 
    if (!(v1.size() == v2.size())) 
        return (bSame = false);     
    for (size_t i = 0, sz = v1.size(); i < sz; ++i) {
        if (!(v1.at(i) == v2.at(i))) 
            bSame = false;      
    }
    return bSame; 
}
```

Implementation 2: (quite similar to [std::equal implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) of cppreference.com)

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool isVecSameV2(std::vector<T1> v1, std::vector<T2> v2) { 
    bool bSame = true; 
    if (!(v1.size() == v2.size()))       
        return (bSame = false);     

    auto itBeg_v1 = v1.begin();
    auto itEnd_v1 = v1.end();
    auto itBeg_v2 = v2.begin();

    for ( ; itBeg_v1 != itEnd_v1; ++itBeg_v1, ++itBeg_v2) {
        if ( !((*itBeg_v1) == (*itBeg_v2)) ) 
            bSame = false;      
    }
    return bSame; 
}
```

(The results of these two implementations are the same, as far as I tested.)

I thought the `std::vector`'s `==` operator works similarly: Compares the size of the two vectors and then compares each element by `==`, if the elements implemented the `==` operator.

Then what can be the cause of the difference between the result of `vector1 == vector2` and the result of the above functions?

P.S. the types `T` of `std::vector<T>` are: `uint64_t`, `std::string`, `int`, `float`. And I didn't overload any operators.

---

<sub>Context: I'm trying to read a text file line by line and parse it into the std::vector, and check if the two vectors from the different read(of the same text file) are the same by using `vector1 == vector2`. Strangely, sometimes vectors were not the same, so that's why I tried to implement custom functions to compare two vectors - which tells me the vectors are the same all the time. (not easy to write a minimal reproducible example because it involves reading a huge text file)</sub>

Comment: You must have some test-cases extracted from the big file.  How about sharing them with us.  Also what types are in the `std::vector<T>` and have any of the operations on `T` been overloaded?

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks! I edited the question. The types are uint64_t, std::string, int, and float. No custom types were used.

Comment: In your code, you expect the type of the elements in two vectors to be different?

Comment: @kuro No, I don't. I just used different types in the template(T1, T2) just for completeness. I also tried only one typename, `T`, but the result was the same.

Comment: Can you show two `vector`s that your `isVecSame` says are equal but `operator==` says are not? Just narrow it down until you find a value they don't agree upon. **1** Read the huge files into `v1` and `v2` and assert that `v1.size() == v2.size() && v1 != v2 && isVecSame(v1,v2) == true`. **2** `decltype(v1.back()) d1{}; decltype(v2.back()) d2{};` **3** `while(not v1.empty() && v1 != v2) { d1 = v1.back(); d2 = v2.back(); v1.resize(v1.size()-1); v2.resize(v2.size()-1); }` **4** Print the values found to not be equal according to `operator==`: `std::cout << d1 << ' ' << d2 << '\n';`

Answer (score 1):

There must be only one template parameter . Types are checked by the standard implementation with the `compat` and `getcont` function. Their iterators must be compatible.

The vectors should be passed as const reference. You are making copies. Potentially with side effects when you use `std::string`. Very unlikely, but possible.

The function must be defined as `const`. Otherwise they will not be compatible with some algorithms.

```
template <typename T>
bool isVecSameV2(const std::vector<T> &v1, const std::vector<T>& v2) const {
```

However. The problem is most likely somewhere else in the code. But we cannot see it . . .

Comment: Thanks for your help! Some points I don't understand: 1) Why there must be only one template parameter? T1 and T2 will be the same type anyway. **2)** How can making copies modify the original object? **3)** Those two functions I implemented are not member functions, so there's no point making them `const`. Also, if `v1` and `v2` are const, how can they be modified regardless of the function being `const` or not?  ...I should research more, but any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. I changed my code as you advised(except for making the functions `const` because they can't be), but the result was the same. I also thought the problem would be somewhere else, but the only difference I made in my code was switching `==` to the above custom functions. So I don't know why those two ways behave differently.